# Помогите установить пакет

Tags: golang

Очень нужно установить пакет для парсинга сайтов. В Го я пока что новичок, а потому никак не могу научиться устанавливать пакет. Здесь нашёл ссылку, но установить не могу. Читаю справку по установке пакетов, читаю форумы, ничего не получается.
Вот ссылка на пакет

```
https://github.com/geziyor/geziyor
```

Comment: [`go get -u github.com/geziyor/geziyor`](https://github.com/geziyor/geziyor#installation)

Answer (score 4):

Напишите в вашей программе `import "github.com/geziyor/geziyor"`
а где-нибудь в коде `geziyor.NewGeziyor()`, сохраните

Затем в консоли выполните команду `go mod tidy` в том каталоге, где у вас `go.mod`. Эта команда автоматически находит импорты внешних библиотек, выкачивает их, компилирует и вносит зависимости в `go.mod` и `go.sum`